# vmware workstation 10.0 installation on ubuntu 14.0.4

Tags: software-installation

when i finished from installing vmware workstation 10.0 on ubuntu 14.0.4 and run its icon this message appear 
Unable to start services.

See log file /tmp/vmware-root/vmware-modconfig-22598.log for details.

Comment: Did you look in that log file like the error suggests?

Answer (score 0):

Thanks budiap for posting patch for Workstation 10! It just took me a while to figure out that you need to use that code to apply that code to a patch file. Here is the post I made to vmware workstation forums.

OKAY! I got it. Workstation 10 on Ubuntu15.04, or whatever-buntu. I tested this on Xubuntu 15.04 Kernel 3.19.0-18-generic

Created new pastie(10215458) for patch for Workstation 10.

After fresh install of Workstation 10.06 Specifically - > VMware-Workstation-Full-10.0.6-2700073.x86_64.bundle

Must be root, but you can basically copy/paste.

curl http://pastie.org/pastes/10215458/download -o /tmp/vmnet-3.19.patch_ws10

cd /usr/lib/vmware/modules/source
tar -xf vmnet.tar
patch -p0 -i /tmp/vmnet-3.19.patch_ws10
mv vmnet.tar vmnet.tar.SAVED
tar -cf vmnet.tar vmnet-only
rm -r vmnet-only
vmware-modconfig --console --install-all